# How to add a Unicode Symbol to a Combobox

Tags: java, swing, unicode, jcombobox

I need to add a division sign as an item in a combobox. This is the formal division sign from grade school math (the one with the single dot above and below the hyphen). In unicode, the code for this symbol is '00f7'.

I tried this code:

```
myComboBox.addItem("\00f7");
```

but it didn't work. I just got a box followed by 'f7'.  I know that this code works for adding strings, so it must be that I'm not dealing with the unicode part correctly.

Can anyone tell me what to change?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with

```
myComboBox.addItem("\u00f7");
```

Unicode starts with "\u"